# Flutter generating errors for pub-cache

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I just had to take over a Flutter project from some devs I have no contact with ... Flutter doctor all checks out ...  The error are all in pub-cache.  I tried flutter clean, flutter pub get ... Here is the start of the errors ...

"Note:

> C:\Users\justi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\agora_rtc_engine-1.0.15\android\src\main\java\io\agora\agorartcengine\AgoraRtcEnginePlugin.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: C:\Users\justi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\agora_rtc_engine-1.0.15\android\src\main\java\io\agora\agorartcengine\AgoraRtcEnginePlugin.java
> uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:unchecked for details. /C:/Users/justi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/circular_check_box-1.0.4/lib/circular_check_box.dart:328:39:
> Error: Type 'RenderToggleable' not found. class
> _RenderCircularCheckBox extends RenderToggleable {
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/Users/justi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/photo-0.4.8/lib/src/ui/widget/check_box_copy.dart:216:31:
> Error: Type 'RenderToggleable' not found. class _RenderCheckbox
> extends RenderToggleable {
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/Users/justi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/photo-0.4.8/lib/src/ui/widget/check_box_copy.dart:187:19:
> Error: The return type of the method
> '_CheckboxRenderObjectWidget.createRenderObject' is '_RenderCheckbox',
> which does not match the return type, 'RenderObject', of the
> overridden method, 'RenderObjectWidget.createRenderObject'.
>
> - '_RenderCheckbox' is from 'package:photo/src/ui/widget/check_box_copy.dart'
>   ('/C:/Users/justi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/photo-0.4.8/lib/src/ui/widget/check_box_copy.dart').
> - 'RenderObject' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart')."

Answer (score 1):

You can try different thigs:

1. `flutter pub cache repair`
2. Delete your `C:/Users/justi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache` folder. (You can create a backup folder if you feel hesitant).

Answer (score 0):

In newer version of flutter RenderToggleable class was removed and this causing problem.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/76745